# iOS UICollectionView bounces back to start when scrolling has stopped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

As in the topic described I have an UICollectionView which can be scrolled horizontal. When the User stops scrolling / dragging it always bounces back to the original position when the view did load but I want that the view stops so the User can select the last item in this view.

```html
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 70) collectionViewLayout:layout];
[collectionView setDataSource:self];
[collectionView setDelegate:self];
[collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[collectionView setScrollEnabled:YES];
collectionView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(500,70);
```

Comment: wow thank you that worked!